# Can I use a WLAN mini pcie card (half or full height) in USB WiFi/WWAN slot?

Tags: usb, wifi, card

I have a mini PC which has an mSATA and a USB WiFi / WWAN slot.
Below is a picture with the board and its slots.
[image]
I want to know if there is a possibility to install a WLAN mini pcie card (half or full height) which supports 5Ghz AC standard into that WWAN slot or if there are any adapters/converters that can be inserted there to be able to use it as a standard mini pcie slot for WiFi cards ?

I have tried with two different mini pcie cards one Compex WLE600VX full height and another Mediatek MT7612E half-height and there are not detected.

Thank you

Comment: Did you confirm that whatever OS is running on your device supports the card(s) you're wanting to use?

Comment: I tried this on several Linux/BSD distributions. These cards do no support Windows. I have tested them on different device and both run fine.

Comment: Linux being Linux, "several Linux/BSD distributions" doesn't mean that it's supported by the specific build which is on that device. Check your kernel messages to see if an PCI device is recognised and if a driver is selected. Also check the result of an lspci command.

Comment: Sorry I meant on a different PC not different Linux distro on the board in the image above. The board above is a XCY X44 mini PC and the cards are not detected at the hardware level nothing is found on lspci output even when drivers are loaded. n fact I have a USB wifi card delivered by the supplier of the board which is working https://www.amazon.com/AzureWave-AW-NU706H-RT3070L-Wireless-300Mbps/dp/B00ENEZ2I4 but it does not support AC standard.

Comment: I have found recently a similar USB 2.0 WiFi card which supports 5GHz AC standards. http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Foxconn_WFUR6. I have seen some reports that it works properly using a similar WWAN slot.
I think this is the only USB 2.0 WiFi card model which supports 5GHz AC.